# Why does this compile with the Dev-C++ compiler and not Visual Studio's one?

Tags: c, visual-studio, dev-c++

Why does the following code compile with the [Dev-C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) compiler and 
not with Visual Studio?

Any idea? Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[n];
    for(i= 0 ; i <n ; i++)
    {
         //Do something with the array 
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}
```

Here are the errors:

[Errors http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/6618/26863513.jpg](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/6618/26863513.jpg)

Comment: Mentioning the compile errors you get would help us to explain them.

Comment: Presumably your compile errors came with line numbers.  Errors 3 and 4 are obvious, but I don't see where error 2 comes from, and there's the question of what error 1 is.

Comment: Error 2 comes from the fact that in C89, all declarations have to be at the top of the function before any other statements. `arr` must be declared before the preceding `scanf` line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
int arr[n];
```

is invalid because `n` is not a constant expression.  You need to allocate variable sized arrays on the heap using `malloc` (and then free them when you are done with `free`).

If you are trying to compile this with a `.cpp` extension, `main` must have a return type of `int`.  If you are trying to compile this with a `.c` extension, then you need to use c-style local variable declaration and declare all of your local variables at the top of the function.

Comment: The `arr[n]` thing is likely your problem. GCC (which Dev-C++ uses) has preliminary support for C99 variable-length arrays, but Visual Studio's compiler does not, hence the compilation failure.

Answer (score 4):

Visual C++ doesn't do stack allocations with that syntax (though I wish it did). You can do stack allocations explicitly with:

```
int *arr = (int *)_alloca(n*sizeof(*arr));
```

and no need to free it since it's automatically freed when the scope ends.

Answer (score 3):

This isn’t valid C++ – the Visual C++ compiler does **not** contain an up-to-date C compiler (rather a C subset of C++) and in particular it doesn’t implement C99 or anything newer. Your code uses features that the Visual C++ compiler doesn’t know (`int arr[n]`).

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the answers you have gotten:

Your code is C99 and Visual C++ only supports C89. Do yourself a favour and get a better compiler for Windows. The Intel compiler has much better support for C99 than the Microsoft compiler (which has none).

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not a Standard compliant program.

Any standard compliant compiler is required to issue a diagnostic when attempting to compile it.

If Dev-C++ compiled it without a warning, the compiler was invoked in a non compliance mode.

Other than the required diagnostic, a compliant compiler can attempt to compile anyway or just plainly abort compilation.

```
main()
```

In C89 this is valid and requires no diagnostic, In C99 this is invalid and requires a diagnostic (valid C99 definitions are `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or equivalent) ... so if you are using a compliant compiler it is a C89 compiler.

```
scanf("%d",&n);
int arr[n];
```

Oops, this is invalid in C89. In C89 you cannot have code intermixed with declarations. A C89 compiler must issue a diagnostic when it sees the declaration of the array.

So ... you are using your compiler in a non-conforming way. There's no way to tell why it compiles or fails to compile.

Comment: Moreover, in C89 it's invalid to declare an array with something that isn't an integer constant.  In C++, it's legal to declare an array with a constant integral expression, but this isn't (the value of n occurs at runtime), and Visual Studio is likely going with the C++ standard here.

Comment: Yeah ... and also `fflush(stdin);`, which is undefined in the Standard (\*), and the missing `return` statement in `main()` (... and not checking the return value of `scanf()` before using the variable). _(\*) some compilers define flushing an input stream as an extension_